# qooxdoo: Enhance property to distinguish 0 from -0

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a possibility to "override" the equality check of the generated property setters?
I like to have a (integer) property that **can** distinguish 0 (zero) from -0 (negative zero).

For example this:

```
qx.Class.define("io.Dummy",
{
  extend : qx.core.Object,
  properties :
  {
    value : {
      check    : "Integer",
      nullable : true,
      init     : null,
      event    : "changeValue"
    }
  }
});
```

so that following code will fire 3 events (instead of only 1):

```
  var dummy = new infodesk.Dummy();
  dummy.addListener("changeValue", function (e) {
    this.info("changed!");
  }, this);

  dummy.setValue(-0); // <= changed!
  dummy.setValue(-0);
  dummy.setValue(+0); // <= changed!
  dummy.setValue(+0);
  dummy.setValue(-0); // <= changed!
  dummy.setValue(-0);
```

When I "patch" the equality-checks in the framework (`qx.core.Property`'s `__emitXxx` methods) by replacing code like "`if (a===b)`" with "`if(Object.is(a,b))`"<sup>[1]</sup> it works,
...but it would be nice if there's a nicer -more clean- way of doing this.

Maybe this is a feature request?
For a property definition attribute like "compare" (Function) or "altCheck" (Boolean)?

```
  properties :
  {
    value : {
      check    : "Integer",
      nullable : true,
      init     : null,
      event    : "changeValue",
      altCheck : true // 'alternative check enabled'
      // rsp.:
      compare : function (a, b) { return Object.is(a, b); }
    }
  }
```

[1] ECMA-Script 6

Comment: this looks like a feature request  :) ... can you please report it to https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues ...also for discussing strategies to solve it, please join us on https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo

Answer (score 0):

As qooxdoo does not offer the functionality of defining a custom value comparer, please open an issue at the github issue tracker at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/ .

I think the idea of having a compare attribute which allows to define a custom comparer is a good idea. If the compare attribute is omitted, the default comparer should be used.

The best way of getting the functionality you need into qooxdoo is to create a pull request which implements the feature, accompanied by unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code you mentioned above and found that "changeValue" event happened only once, not 3 times! I use [Qooxdoo Playground v5.0.1](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/playground), Firefox 47.0, Win7.

What's wrong?

You can solve the problem by using the [transform](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/pages/core/defining_properties.html#transforming-incoming-values) key of qooxdoo property, saving the data as string instead of an integer.

Comment: I made the same mistake - the OP *wants* to distinguish between +0 and -0, but the framework does not

Comment: Oh, I see. I do believe that it is possible to solve the problem without changing The Properties System of qooxdoo. There is no need to modify the framework to be able to distiguish between +0/-0 at all.